# Shopify: Slide show images don't aspect fit to the banner area; they get cropped

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid, slick.js

I am using shopify theme 'Pop' which comes with a Slick Slider Hero. When the slideshow is opened on a mobile device, it automatically crops my images which I don't want because I added text to the image so it cuts it off (view pic attached)

Please let me know what code to add to what liquid/css file so that it resizes picture instead of cutting it off.

Thank you so much!

### Theme code

```
<div data-section-id="{{ section.id }}" data-section-type="slideshow-section">

  {% if section.blocks.size > 0 %}
    <div class="slideshow-wrapper">
      <button type="button" class="visually-hidden slideshow__pause" data-id="{{ section.id }}" aria-live="polite">
        <span class="slideshow__pause-stop">
          {% include 'icon-pause' %}
          <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 'sections.slideshow.pause_slideshow' | t }}</span>
        </span>
        <span class="slideshow__pause-play">
          {% include 'icon-play' %}
          <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 'sections.slideshow.play_slideshow' | t }}</span>
        </span>
      </button>

      <div class="slideshow slideshow--{{ section.settings.slideshow_height }}" id="Slideshow-{{ section.id }}" data-autoplay="{{ section.settings.autoplay }}" data-speed="{{ section.settings.autoplay_speed }}">
        {% for block in section.blocks %}
          {%- assign is_background_video = false -%}
          {% if block.type == 'video' %}
            {% if block.settings.video_type == 'background' or block.settings.video_type =='background-chrome' %}
              {%- assign is_background_video = true -%}
            {% endif %}
          {% endif %}

          <div class="slideshow__slide slideshow__slide--{{ block.id }}{% if is_background_video %} slideshow__slide--background-video{% endif %}" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
            {% if block.settings.link != blank %}
              <a href="{{ block.settings.link }}" class="slideshow__link">
            {% endif %}

            {% if block.type == 'video' %}
              {% if block.settings.video_url != blank %}
                <div class="video-loader"></div>
              {% endif %}
              {% unless block.settings.video_type == 'background' %}
                <button type="button" class="text-link slideshow__video-control slideshow__video-control--close" data-controls="SlideshowVideo-{{ block.id }}">
                  {% include 'icon-close' %}
                  <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 'sections.slideshow.close_video' | t }}</span>
                </button>
              {% endunless %}
              {% if block.settings.video_url != blank %}
                <div id="SlideshowVideo-{{ block.id }}" class="slideshow__video {% if is_background_video %}slideshow__video--background{% endif %} slideshow__video--{{ block.settings.video_type }}"
                  data-id="{{ block.settings.video_url.id }}"
                  data-type="{{ block.settings.video_type }}"
                  data-slideshow="Slideshow-{{ section.id }}"></div>
              {% endif %}
            {% endif %}

            {% if block.settings.image == blank %}
              <div class="slideshow__image js">
                <div class="placeholder-background">
                  {% capture current %}{% cycle 1, 2 %}{% endcapture %}
                  {{ 'lifestyle-' | append: current | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
                </div>
              </div>
            {% else %}

              <div class="slideshow__image box ratio-container lazyload{% unless forloop.first == true %} lazypreload{% endunless %} js"
                   data-bgset="{% include 'bgset', image: block.settings.image %}"
                   data-sizes="auto"
                   data-parent-fit="cover"
                   style="background-position: {{ block.settings.alignment }};{% if forloop.first == true %} background-image: url('{{ block.settings.image | img_url: '300x300' }});{% endif %}">
              </div>
            {% endif %}

            <noscript>
              <div class="slideshow__image"{% if block.settings.image %} style="background-image: url('{{ block.settings.image | img_url: '2048x' }}'); background-position: {{ block.settings.alignment }};"{% endif %}>
                {% if block.settings.image == blank %}
                  <div class="placeholder-background">
                    {% capture current %}{% cycle 1, 2 %}{% endcapture %}
                    {{ 'lifestyle-' | append: current | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
                  </div>
                {% endif %}
              </div>
            </noscript>
            <div class="slideshow__text-wrap{% if block.settings.title != blank or block.settings.subheading != blank %} slideshow__overlay{% endif %}">
              <div class="slideshow__text-content">
                <div class="page-width">
                  {% unless block.settings.title == blank %}
                    <h2 class="h1 mega-title slideshow__title{% if settings.link != blank %} slideshow__title--has-link{% endif %}{% if section.settings.text_size == 'large' %} mega-title--large{% endif %}">
                      {{ block.settings.title | escape }}
                    </h2>
                  {% endunless %}
                  {% unless block.settings.subheading == blank %}
                    <span class="mega-subtitle slideshow__subtitle{% if section.settings.text_size == 'large' %} mega-subtitle--large{% endif %}">
                      {{ block.settings.subheading | escape }}
                    </span>
                  {% endunless %}
                  {% if block.type == 'video' %}
                    {% unless block.settings.video_type == 'background' %}
                      <div class="slideshow__video-control--play-wrapper{% if block.settings.title != blank or block.settings.subheading != blank %} slideshow__video-control--play-wrapper--push{% endif %}">
                        <button type="button" class="text-link slideshow__video-control slideshow__video-control--play" data-controls="SlideshowVideo-{{ block.id }}">
                          {% include 'icon-play-video' %}
                          <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 'sections.slideshow.play_video' | t }}</span>
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    {% endunless %}
                  {% endif %}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            {% if block.settings.link != blank %}
              </a>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endif %}

  {% if section.blocks.size == 0 %}
    <div class="placeholder-noblocks">
      {{ 'homepage.onboarding.no_content' | t }}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

### Generated HTML Code

```
<div id="shopify-section-1531416277337" class="shopify-section index-section index-section--flush" data-theme-editor-section-36470275618="{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1531416277337&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;slideshow&quot;,&quot;disabled&quot;:false}">
    <div data-section-id="1531416277337" data-section-type="slideshow-section">

        <div class="slideshow-wrapper">
            <button type="button" class="visually-hidden slideshow__pause" data-id="1531416277337" aria-live="polite">
                <span class="slideshow__pause-stop">
          <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="presentation" class="icon icon-pause" viewBox="0 0 10 13"><g fill="#000" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="M0 0h3v13H0zM7 0h3v13H7z"></path></g></svg>
          <span class="icon__fallback-text">Pause slideshow</span>
                </span>
                <span class="slideshow__pause-play">
          <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="presentation" class="icon icon-play" viewBox="0 0 18 32"><path d="M.263 0l17.071 15.944L.264 31.89" fill="#444" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
          <span class="icon__fallback-text">Play slideshow</span>
                </span>
            </button>

            <div class="slideshow slideshow--medium slick-initialized slick-slider slick-dotted" id="Slideshow-1531416277337" data-autoplay="true" data-speed="5000">

                <div class="slick-list draggable">
                    <div class="slick-track" style="opacity: 1; width: 750px;">
                        <div class="slideshow__slide slideshow__slide--1531416277337-0 slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false" role="tabpanel" id="slickSlide10" aria-labelledby="slickDot10" tabindex="-1" data-theme-editor-block-36470275618="{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1531416277337-0&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;image&quot;}" style="width: 375px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 999; opacity: 1;">

                            <div class="slideshow__image box ratio-container js lazyloaded" data-bgset="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66_180x.jpg?v=1531416305 180w 114h,
    //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66_360x.jpg?v=1531416305 360w 228h,
    //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66_540x.jpg?v=1531416305 540w 342h,
    //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66_720x.jpg?v=1531416305 720w 456h,
    //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66_900x.jpg?v=1531416305 900w 571h,
    //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66_1080x.jpg?v=1531416305 1080w 685h,
    //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66_1296x.jpg?v=1531416305 1296w 822h,
    //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66_1512x.jpg?v=1531416305 1512w 958h,
    //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66_1728x.jpg?v=1531416305 1728w 1095h,

    //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66.jpg?v=1531416305 1923w 1219h" data-parent-fit="cover" style="background-position: center bottom; background-image: url(&quot;https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66.jpg?v=1531416305&quot;);">
                                <picture style="display: none;">
                                    <source data-srcset="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66_180x.jpg?v=1531416305 180w 114h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66_360x.jpg?v=1531416305 360w 228h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66_540x.jpg?v=1531416305 540w 342h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66_720x.jpg?v=1531416305 720w 456h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66_900x.jpg?v=1531416305 900w 571h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66_1080x.jpg?v=1531416305 1080w 685h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66_1296x.jpg?v=1531416305 1296w 822h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66_1512x.jpg?v=1531416305 1512w 958h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66_1728x.jpg?v=1531416305 1728w 1095h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66.jpg?v=1531416305 1923w 1219h" sizes="789.4736842105262px" srcset="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66_180x.jpg?v=1531416305 180w 114h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66_360x.jpg?v=1531416305 360w 228h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66_540x.jpg?v=1531416305 540w 342h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66_720x.jpg?v=1531416305 720w 456h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66_900x.jpg?v=1531416305 900w 571h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66_1080x.jpg?v=1531416305 1080w 685h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66_1296x.jpg?v=1531416305 1296w 822h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66_1512x.jpg?v=1531416305 1512w 958h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66_1728x.jpg?v=1531416305 1728w 1095h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66.jpg?v=1531416305 1923w 1219h"><img alt="" class="lazyautosizes lazyloaded" data-sizes="auto" data-parent-fit="cover" sizes="789.4736842105262px"></picture>
                            </div>

                            <noscript>
                                <div class="slideshow__image" style="background-image: url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/beach_trash2_3c79e4e7-49ad-4ef3-ace0-103c1d531b66_2048x.jpg?v=1531416305'); background-position: bottom;">

                                </div>
                            </noscript>
                            <div class="slideshow__text-wrap">
                                <div class="slideshow__text-content">
                                    <div class="page-width">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="slideshow__slide slideshow__slide--1531416277337-1 slick-slide" data-slick-index="1" aria-hidden="true" role="tabpanel" id="slickSlide11" aria-labelledby="slickDot11" tabindex="-1" data-theme-editor-block-36470275618="{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1531416277337-1&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;image&quot;}" style="width: 375px; position: relative; left: -375px; top: 0px; z-index: 998; opacity: 0; transition: opacity 500ms ease;">

                            <div class="slideshow__image box ratio-container lazypreload js lazyloaded" data-bgset="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles_180x.jpg?v=1531419269 180w 120h,
    //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles_360x.jpg?v=1531419269 360w 240h,
    //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles_540x.jpg?v=1531419269 540w 360h,
    //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles_720x.jpg?v=1531419269 720w 480h,
    //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles_900x.jpg?v=1531419269 900w 600h,
    //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles_1080x.jpg?v=1531419269 1080w 720h,
    //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles_1296x.jpg?v=1531419269 1296w 864h,
    //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles_1512x.jpg?v=1531419269 1512w 1008h,
    //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles_1728x.jpg?v=1531419269 1728w 1152h,

    //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles.jpg?v=1531419269 1920w 1280h" data-parent-fit="cover" style="background-position: center top; background-image: url(&quot;https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles.jpg?v=1531419269&quot;);">
                                <picture style="display: none;">
                                    <source data-srcset="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles_180x.jpg?v=1531419269 180w 120h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles_360x.jpg?v=1531419269 360w 240h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles_540x.jpg?v=1531419269 540w 360h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles_720x.jpg?v=1531419269 720w 480h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles_900x.jpg?v=1531419269 900w 600h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles_1080x.jpg?v=1531419269 1080w 720h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles_1296x.jpg?v=1531419269 1296w 864h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles_1512x.jpg?v=1531419269 1512w 1008h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles_1728x.jpg?v=1531419269 1728w 1152h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles.jpg?v=1531419269 1920w 1280h" sizes="750px" srcset="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles_180x.jpg?v=1531419269 180w 120h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles_360x.jpg?v=1531419269 360w 240h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles_540x.jpg?v=1531419269 540w 360h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles_720x.jpg?v=1531419269 720w 480h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles_900x.jpg?v=1531419269 900w 600h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles_1080x.jpg?v=1531419269 1080w 720h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles_1296x.jpg?v=1531419269 1296w 864h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles_1512x.jpg?v=1531419269 1512w 1008h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles_1728x.jpg?v=1531419269 1728w 1152h, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles.jpg?v=1531419269 1920w 1280h"><img alt="" class="lazyautosizes lazyloaded" data-sizes="auto" data-parent-fit="cover" sizes="750px"></picture>
                            </div>

                            <noscript>
                                <div class="slideshow__image" style="background-image: url('//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2543/3412/files/bottles_2048x.jpg?v=1531419269'); background-position: top;">

                                </div>
                            </noscript>
                            <div class="slideshow__text-wrap">
                                <div class="slideshow__text-content">
                                    <div class="page-width">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <ul class="slick-dots" style="display: block;" role="tablist">
                    <li class="slick-active" aria-hidden="false" role="tab" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="slickSlide10" id="slickDot10">
                        <button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" tabindex="0">Slide 1</button>
                    </li>
                    <li role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="slickSlide11" id="slickDot11" class="">
                        <button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" tabindex="0">Slide 2</button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

### CSS Code

```
/*================ Slick Slider SCSS ================*/
.slick-slider {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
  touch-action: pan-y;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
.slick-list {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }

  &.dragging {
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
  }
}
.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;

  &:before,
  &:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
  }

  &:after {
    clear: both;
  }

  .slick-loading & {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
.slick-slide {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  [dir="rtl"] & {
    float: right;
  }
  img {
    display: block;
  }
  &.slick-loading img {
    display: none;
  }

  display: none;

  &.dragging img {
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  .slick-initialized & {
    display: block;
  }

  .slick-loading & {
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  .slick-vertical & {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
  }
}
.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

### Example Image

[image: Cropped Slideshow Image]

Comment: How can we tell you what code to add, change or remove when you've not provided any for us to check?

Comment: Could you give us the code ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new on this site : I've edited my question and added the code from the theme.scss.liquid

Comment: adding `ul.slides img { max-width:100%;}` should prevent the image from getting cut off.